# The thread 'MainThread' (0x339c) has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am using visual studio, when I run this code below I am getting this message and the program did not run correctly:

The thread 'MainThread' (0x339c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The program '[10996] python.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

`from selenium import webdriver
path = chrome_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get('https://google.com/')`

Comment: Exit code 0 usually means the program exited without any errors. What happens if you run it outside of visual studio?

Comment: If I run it outside visual studio it works fine.

Comment: when I run it inside visual studio the Chrome browser is not launching

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is displaying the contents of `stdout` and `stderr`. When each thread and finally the entire program exits, it'll show that they exited and the code they returned when they exited.

Your program doesn't `print` anything to `stdout` *or* `stderr`, which is why no output appears before the program exits.

Your problem with Chrome could be caused by running 32-bit Visual Studio or 32-bit Python on a 64-bit machine, causing it not to find the 32-bit version of Chrome in the 32-bit folder (because the 32-bit folder is just ordinary `Program Files` as far as a 32-bit program is concerned).